# numpy array not broadcastable

Tags: python, numpy

This is an example of my error.  Say i created a numpy array

```
X = np.zeros((1000, 50))
```

Where 1000 is the features (rows) and 50 is the examples (columns)

Since i am adding examples one by one i will have to replace columns in the array 1 by 1 to get the final feature array.  I tried this:

```
X[:,i] = example
```

where example is of size (1000, 1), and `i` is iterated for every example.  This does not work because X[:,i] is of shape (1000,), a rank 1 array.  How do i code it so that each example replaces a row of the X array without throwing the broadcast error.  Thank you.

Comment: `X[:,i] = example.reshape(1000)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape your vector before assigning it.

```
X[:,i] = example.reshape(-1,)
```

This will suppress the second dimension and turn `example` into shape (1000,)

Or, avoiding assigning one by one in the loop you can put all of your arrays in a list and then call `np.array` on your list and transpose it to have them as columns. This will probably work better if you can construct your list of arrays in a list comprehension.

Example:

```
arrs = [np.random.randint(10, size=5) for _ in range(5)]
X = np.array(arrs).T
```

Comment: First solution worked,  I will try to use a method like the second in the future, Thanks!